# printing an element of array (python)

Tags: python, arrays, printing

There are two lists/arrays and I want to assign one by one.

```
import Mybench
process = []
benchmarks = options.benchmark.split(',')
for bench_name in benchmarks:
   process.append(getattr(Mybench, bench_name))
```

Assume another list (cpus) is also created. Now I want to do this:

```
i = 0
for i, cpu in cpus:
   print "cpu", i, "assigned to ", process[i]
   cpu.workload = process[i]
   i = i+1
```

However in the output I see:

```
cpu 0 assigned to  <orphan LiveProcess>
```

LiveProcess() is returned from Mybench.
How can I fis that?

Answer (score 0):

```
for i, cpu in enumerate(cpus):
   print "cpu", i, "assigned to ", process[i]
   cpu.workload = process[i]
```

Comment: cpu.workload = process[i]
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'workload'

Comment: @mahmood What's `cpu`? can you give an example of it?

Comment: I didn't write this. It is part of the program source code.  np = options.num_cpus ;;;
    cpus = [DerivO3CPU(cpu_id = i, clock='1.0GHz')
            for i in xrange(np)]

Comment: @mahmood it seem that it's a `tuple`, then you can't write `cpu.workload`

Comment: what do you recommend then?There is no problem with that. I mean cpu.workload=process[i] works without problem.

Comment: never mind... I wanted to see if that is possible then print some information. I don't know the implementation of DerivO3CPU. sorry for taking up your time

Comment: alright, I got it. `cpus ` is a list of DerivO3CPU, so you can use `for i, cpu in cpus:`

Comment: @mahmood but there is no need for `i = 0` and `i = i + 1`